# Access json object with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do exactly is to access
array_from_php.api_description.{ACTION_VARIABLE}.param

This following script works:

```
$('select[name="action"]').change(function(){
    var action = $(this).val();
    var new_form = '';
    $.each(array_from_php.api_description.register_mobile.param, function(i, param) {
        new_form += '<label for="label">'+param+': </label>';
        new_form += '<input type="text" name="'+param+'" value=""><br />';

    });
    $(".parameters").html(new_form);

});
```

but how can I change the `register_mobile` to the action variable im gettin there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using bracket notation:

```
$('select[name="action"]').change(function(){
    var action = $(this).val();
    var new_form = '';
    $.each(array_from_php.api_description[action].param, function(i, param) {
        new_form += '<label for="label">'+param+': </label>';
        new_form += '<input type="text" name="'+param+'" value=""><br />';

    });
    $(".parameters").html(new_form);

});
```